# Getting Invalid top-level type in JSON write iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, java

Im trying to parse json responce using AFNetworking but it return me error ;

> Invalid top-level type in JSON writes

but my json is as below and nothing problem regarding json format, i check JSON online and it's fine.

```
{
  "Result": {
    "RoomDetail": [
      {
        "RoomName": "crs",
        "NaturalName": "aaa"
      },
      {
        "RoomName": "ios",
        "NaturalName": "ios"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my code that i used :

```
-(void)CallRoom
{
    @try {
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *managers = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

        NSMutableDictionary *parameter = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           @"bhavin",@"userName",
                                           nil];

        NSString *setUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/OpenFire-Chat/getChatRoomsByUser.htm"];

        managers.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

        [managers POST:setUrl parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            NSError *writeError = nil;
            NSData *jsonData;

            //if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:responseObject])
            {
                jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
            }


            NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                  error:&writeError];
        }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
     }


}
```

**EDIT**

OK, So there's an error in my Web Service API:

I didn't set ContentType in Response header to `application/Json.`

Comment: hide this ` jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError]; ` and this `managers.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];`  and try once

Comment: by commenting responseSerializer, it give me error : Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

Comment: in which line u facing the error

Comment: it direct send to ''failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation"

Comment: @Kabali You are missing `content-type`. For that please check my answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Kabali My answer is working so you have to accept my answer. That is motivation for us so hope you accept my answer.

Comment: your answer tells me to add contenType in XCode,but my problem is with Web API, so i cann't declare that your ans helps me. Thx for help.

Comment: @Kabali Atleast I point out that where you did mistake. So you have to accept that. If you do like this then no one can help you.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are missing **acceptableContentTypes**.

Just try to below code :

```
AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[serializer setStringEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer=serializer;

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html",@"application/json", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *parameter = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"bhavin",@"userName",
                                  nil];

NSString *setUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/OpenFire-Chat/getChatRoomsByUser.htm"];

[manager POST:setUrl parameters:parameter progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
     {
         //log responseObject
     } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

     }];
```

Comment: acceptableContentTypes is missing in my web service.. thx for help.

Comment: @EktaPadaliya Thanks. Nice Answer

Comment: @JagatDave Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to convert data in Json format, cause AFHTTPRequestOperationManager always return in id.

Write this code in Response

NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSMutableArray new];
dataArray = [responseObject mutableCopy]

Comment: userName is my key and bhavin is value so its ok here... with 'initWithObjectsAndKeys'

Answer (score 0):

You not need to do this,

```
 jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
```

As you are using `AFNetworking` ,it has already serialized data in json object.

So remove,

```
 {
            jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
        }
```

and

you can print to directly like,

```
 NSLog(@"%@",responseObject)
```

or you can fetch your desired value from your `responseObject` directly.

**Update :**

Replace your whole code with,

```
   @try {


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    AFURLSessionManager *managers = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];



    NSMutableDictionary *parameter = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      @"bhavin",@"userName",
                                      nil];

    NSString *setUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/OpenFire-Chat/getChatRoomsByUser.htm"];



    AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:setUrl parameters:parameter error:nil];

    [[managers dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        NSLog(@"response Object : %@",responseObject);

    }]resume];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
}
```

Comment: my responseObject is <7b225265 73756c74 223a7b22 526f6f6d 44657461 696c223a 5b7b2252 6f6f6d4e 616d6522 3a226372 73222c22 4e617475 72616c4e 616d6522 3a226161 61227d2c 7b22526f 6f6d4e61 6d65223a 22696f73 222c224e 61747572 616c4e61 6d65223a 22696f73 227d5d7d 7d>

Comment: @Kabali - it s data yu need to convert data to dict or array using json serlization

Comment: @Kabali : have you tried my updated answer? I have updated again!!

Answer (score 0):

try this to get your data inside the success block....

```
NSDictionary *allresult = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
NSDictionary *Result = [allresult objectForKey:@"Result"];
NSArray *roomDetail = [Result objectForKey:@"RoomDetail"];

for(NSDictionary *rooms in roomDetail)
{
    NSString *roomname = [rooms objectForKey:@"RoomName"];
    NSString *naturalName = [rooms objectForKey:@"NaturalName"];
    NSLog(@"roomname : %@ ---> naturalname : %@", roomname, naturalName);
}
```

Comment: my responseObject is <7b225265 73756c74 223a7b22 526f6f6d 44657461 696c223a 5b7b2252 6f6f6d4e 616d6522 3a226372 73222c22 4e617475 72616c4e 616d6522 3a226161 61227d2c 7b22526f 6f6d4e61 6d65223a 22696f73 222c224e 61747572 616c4e61 6d65223a 22696f73 227d5d7d 7d>

Comment: try this line in success block and tell me what is the output result(look it with a break point.) `NSDictionary *allresult = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;`

Comment: its same result : <7b225265 73756c74 223a7b22 526f6f6d 44657461 696c223a 5b7b2252 6f6f6d4e 616d6522 3a226372 73222c22 4e617475 72616c4e 616d6522 3a226161 61227d2c 7b22526f 6f6d4e61 6d65223a 22696f73 222c224e 61747572 616c4e61 6d65223a 22696f73 227d5d7d 7d>